# React: What's the purpose of checking if a prop is a function to execute it then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having the following code:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
    handleOnClick = () => {
        console.log('inside function');
        if(typeof this.props.onClick === 'function') {
            this.props.onClick(); /* Why this */
        }
    }
    render() {
        const {extraClass} = this.props;
        return (
           <div className={ ${(extraClass)} }>             
           <Component2 onClick={ this.handleOnClick } />
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I don't fully understand the reason of checking if the '*onClick*' prop is a function to then execute it (again?).

As far as I understand, the handleClick is already excecuted when we click on the *Component2* element (*onClick={ this.handleOnClick }*).

What am I missing?

Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: after click event the prop `onClick` won't be called if it is not a function

Comment: There is no point, if your app implemented `onClick` as something dumb like a Boolean then it should hard fail, not silently fail. If `onClick` is optional a falsy check would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Component1` is made up of a `div` and `Component2`. `Component2` has a function that he needs to call when he is clicked. That function is called `handleOnClick`, and it is defined by `Component1`.

In the `handleOnClick` function of `Component1` (which gets called when `Component2` is clicked), you are checking on the type of `this.props.onClick`. **NOTE** that `this.props.onClick` is *what was passed to **`Component1`** by the parent (for example, `App`)*.

No matter what, `handleOnClick` will get called when `Component2` is clicked. It's a function, and we know it's a function because it's defined right there.

But, what we don't know is what the parent of `Component1` passed as a prop (called `onClick`) when that parent decided to use `Component1`. He may have passed a function (in which case, call that function). But he may have passed a string, or perhaps not passed anything at all (in which case, don't call it, because it's not a function).

That's why you need to check on the `typeof this.props.onClick`.

---

Or to put it another way. Let's assume that `App` is the parent that uses `Component1`.

`App` says:

> Ok, I want a `Component1`. And when he's clicked (whatever that means), I want him to call this function that I'm passing to him as a prop, which I'll call `onClick`.

`Component1` says:

> So, I've got this prop called `onClick`. But not all of me is "clickable". Only the `Component2` part of me is "clickable." So, I guess, when `Component2` is clicked, I'll need to make sure I call this function that was passed to me as the `onClick` prop. Oh, but I better make sure that my parent who passed me this `onClick` prop actually passed me a function, or else bad things are gonna happen.

`Component2` says:

> So, when I get clicked, I'll just call `handleOnClick`, which belongs to `Component1`. It's his job to figure out what happens there.

---

#### Update

OP asked in a comment for an example of where it'd be beneficial that the click of a child component executes the function passed as a prop by the parent.

The basic principle is this:

> Whenever the parent **needs to be notified** that a child has been clicked, then the parent needs to pass a handler to that child, and the child is responsible for calling that handler whenever he is clicked.

The parent might "need to be notified" because he needs to take that information and tell some other child to go do something, or because he wants to update his state, or because he wants to log it to the console. There are tons of reasons why a parent might want to know when something has happened to his child (in coding, and in real life). And the *function callback passed as a prop* is the way to accomplish this.

This same practice extends beyond just when a child is clicked. It can apply if the parent needs to know when a child is moused over, or when a child element has a form input which has had its value changed, or when a child element reaches out to a server with a request and gets a response, etc...

---

To demonstrate this in a rudimentary fashion, I've coded up a quick Code Sandbox for you to see. The parent is `App`. It has `Component1` as its child. In fact, it has 3 instances of `Component1` for its children. `Component1` keeps a counter of how many times he is individually clicked. **But** he also lets his parent know (through the function callback passed as a prop) when he has been clicked, so that the parent can keep track of the total number of clicks across all of his children.

[image: Edit Parents capturing child clicks]

Lastly, I highly recommend this article in ReactJS documentation which is entitled ["Lifting State Up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). It gives an excellent explanation of this parent-child interaction and how/why you would let information flow back and forth between the two.

Comment: I like how every answer to this question increases in length/explanation/examples. This is probably the most useful one to OP!

Comment: @Alvin Lee thank you so much for your explanation. Now I see it clear.

Comment: My problem was that I confused the onClick prop of the Component1, with the onClick of the Component2. Although I understand it fully now, could you tell me a practical case where it'd be beneficial that the click on the child component executes the function passed as a prop to the Parent?

Comment: @Barleby I'm glad the explanation was helpful to you. I've updated my answer with an example which you can play around with to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is not passed as the prop value, it would essentially have some other type or `undefined` if no prop is passed. Hence this check is necessary to prevent error. This is same as

```
const x = {};
x.g();
```

There is no method `g` defined in x. Hence if you try to invoke, it'll throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't fully understand the reason of checking if the 'onClick' prop is a function to then execute it (again?).

```
if(typeof this.props.onClick === 'function') {
    this.props.onClick(); /* Why this */
}
```

`props.onClick` could be something different than function, and then props.onClick() would fail with error.

example:

```
const notFunction = 'definitely not function';
notFunction();
 // Uncaught TypeError: notFunction is not a function
 // at <anonymous>:2:1
```

There is bigger chance that `props.onClick` would just not be defined at all more than not being a function. Nice way of handling this situation is to define component's defaultProps:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    onClick: () => null,
  }

  // every time you use props.onClick now you have assurance that it is a function 
  // rather than undefined

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this.props.onClick` you arent executing the function. To execute a function you need to use `()` like `this.props.onClick()`. When you use `typeof this.props.onClick === 'function'` you are checking for the function's prototype and seeing if it's type is a function or not.

You check that to avoid getting an error like `TypeError: something is not a function`. But in your case, you don't need to check it. But there is some cases where is very good to check it, like when using callbacks

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's good practice to always check your prop for event handling is defined and whether or not it is a function, else, if you blindly pass `this.props.onClick` to your Component's `onClick` and if it could at some point be undefined, you would get an error.

`this.handleClick` is a function that is always present so that is immediately executed when your component is clicked and you don't need to check its type/presence, `this.props.onClick` is a different function that is subsequently called inside of it and as it is defined somewhere else, you can't be 100% sure it is what you think it is.

I mean most of the time you can be sure but what if you only wanted the function to be called if a record is loaded - you would pass `onClick` down like `onClick={record.id ? this.handleOnClick : undefined}`. The check would necessary to stop it from erroring.